# Windows SendMessage constant reference?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, sendmessage

There is a list of all SendMessage constants with their little description of the purpose for each message?

I've found this, but does not explain any of the constants:
http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

I can search into MSDN for a specific constant to know what it does, but I want to know in a easy way which is the purpose of each message, for example reading a list of the constants with a little description of each one.

Where I can find some info like that?

Comment: Closure reason please?

Comment: Entire books have been written concerning the purpose and use of them.  And very thick books at that.

Comment: But @Plutonix I'm asking for Internet information, not to buy specific books, is totally different... anyways I don't know the name of a book related about windows messages and their constant variable purposes, I don't have any info that I need about windows message constants :(, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'easy way to know the purpose of each message' it takes several paragraphs or pages to describe the intricacies of how to use them (and 'easy way' does not automatically mean internet/online).

The Constants are somewhat descriptive in themselves, but for an online, searchable reference look at [the PInvoke site](http://pinvoke.net/).  I thought the old Win32API add-in for VB6 was great too.

EDIT  BOOKS

The `Win32 SDK` by Microsoft (three volumes) was excellent.  It is all online in MSDN now, but the book format was excellently laid out.

`Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to the Win32 API` by Dan Appelman was basically a rehash of the SDK (as they all more or less are) but with VB4/5/6 examples.

All of [Petzold's books](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html) are pretty much the gold standard for the Win32 API.

Comment: Thankyou @Plutonix, I knew the Pinvoke site but is not what I'm looking for, maybe you can recommend me a name of one of those books that you've commented? I want to learn this windows messages in the right way, but I do not live in USA so the price + the transport of an English book to my country could costs much money for me, I need a book which I can found a PDF/printable version on internet.